# How to use shift and offset attributes in function fillPoly

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking for easiest way to apply an offset to minimize mask on the image. I tried to use function fillPoly. The names of attributes 'shift' and 'offset', especially the latter one sounded good. Unfortunately I got error: -215 Assertion failed, when I tried to use it.

I cannot find any examples with usage of these attributes. Can any body point me ?

It's not the whole code but help understand my issue.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > fillContAll;  
fillContAll.push_back(fillContSingle);  
cv::Mat maska;  
srcImage.copyTo(maska);  
maska.setTo(0);  
cv::fillPoly(maska, fillContAll, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255),8,50);  
// I tried also cv::fillPoly(maska, fillContAll, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255),8,(5,5));
```

The whole error message is:

exception thrown!
OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2005: error: (-215:Assertion failed) pts && npts && ncontours >= 0 && 0 <= shift && shift <= XY_SHIFT in function 'cv::fillPoly'

Comment: Does the assertion failed error have any more information in the error? Does it give you a line number? Does this compile?

Comment: `fillPoly` looks like it wants a double pointer of `Points`, not a `std::vector<std::vector<cv::point>>`. Am I looking at the wrong documentation? What documentation are you using?

Comment: In this form cv::fillPoly(maska, fillContAll, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255)); all works perfectly.

Comment: In that case you are I are using different documentation. Please let me know what opencv documentation you are using so we can be on the same page.

Comment: @John I use https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/